# How can delay my node-red docker service with docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, node-red

I think that I am facing a race condition with docker compose.

I have a service (B) that needs to connect to another service (A), both are run from the same docker compose file. Along with them,  I have another service (C) which is launched the last one and that it `links` to A too.

What I see is that if I enable C service ( in the docker compose file) then service B stalls and stops working, whereas if I run just A and B the starting goes fine. This to me seems like a race condition within docker, could someone advise me what to do?

PS: My service C is a build of node-red ( using npm installation in docker), so it is not an OS by itself, which limits me while using some docker solutions available.

Regards

Thanks in advance,

EDIT: my docker-compose

```
version: '2'

services:
  rabbitmq: #service A
  #...
  handler: #service B
    image: thethingsnetwork/ttn:latest
    command: handler --config /etc/ttn/handler/conf.yml
    depends_on:
      - discovery
      - redis
      - rabbitmq
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - handler.local
    ports:
      - "1904:1904"
      - "8084:8084"
    volumes:
      - "$HOME/host/handler:/etc/ttn/handler"

  node-red: #service C
    build: $HOME/host/nodeRed
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/node-red/:/root/.node-red/
    depends_on:
      - handler
      - rabbitmq
      - broker
    ports:
      - "1880:1880"
      - "5044:5044" #mapping logs
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. You may want to include your compose file so people can get a clearer view of what you are trying to do

Comment: I have added the partial docker-compose, where node-red depends on those services, the handler is process B

Answer (score 0):

As @hardillb states in the comment, it would be nice to see the docker-compose.yml file but I guess you would need to use the option depends_on, something like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql-int:
    image: mysql:5.6.27
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    container_name: mysql
  test-int:
    build: ../test
    depends_on:
      - mysql-int
    container_name: test
```

Answer (score 0):

depends_on will not work here, it does only give you the "the container started pid1 just right now" - that does not mean, e.g. that you container will have his sockets up and running, lets say the mysql-server is ready for connections.

The general pattern is, lets say we have db as mysql container, and app as the application, while app need the db to be started first ( fully )

```
version: '2'
services:
db:
  image: mysql      
app:
  image: me/myapp
```

Then, the entrypoint of your app image does this in the top of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# this script does only exist to wait for the database before we fire up tomcat / standalone

RET=1
echo "Waiting for database"
while [[ RET -ne 0 ]]; do
    sleep 1;
    if [ -z "${db_password}" ]; then
        mysql -h $db_host -u $db_user -e "select 1" > /dev/null 2>&1; RET=$?
    else
        mysql -h $db_host -u $db_user -p$db_password -e "select 1" > /dev/null 2>&1; RET=$?
    fi
done
```

Adjust host/db/port to the mysql port.

You can also do this a more generic approach by using a tcp socket connection test with wait-for-it: https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it

You find a general topic in the docker docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/